# scrape text from webpage using python 2.7

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from this website:
[Death Row Information](http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html)

I'm having trouble to scrape the last statements from all the executed offenders in the list because the last statement is located at another HTML page. The name of the URL is built like this: http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/[lastname][firstname].html. I can't think of a way of how I can scrape the last statements from these pages and put them in an Sqlite database.

All the other info (expect for "offender information", which I don't need) is already in my datbase.

Anyone who can give me a pointer to get started getting this done in Python?

Thanks

Edit2: I got a little bit further:

```
import sqlite3
import csv
import re
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
URLS = []
Lastwords = {}

conn = sqlite3.connect('prison.sqlite')
conn.text_factory = str
cur = conn.cursor()

# Make some fresh tables using executescript()
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS prison")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Prison ( link1 text, link2 text,Execution text, LastName text, Firstname text, TDCJNumber text, Age integer, date text, race text, county text)")
conn.commit()


csvfile = open("prisonfile.csv","rb")
creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
for t in creader:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO  Prison VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', t, )

for column in cur.execute("SELECT LastName, Firstname FROM prison"):
    lastname = column[0].lower()
    firstname = column[1].lower()
    name = lastname+firstname
    CleanName = name.translate(None, ",.!-@'#$" "")
    CleanName2 = CleanName.replace(" ", "")
    Url = "http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/"
    Link = Url+CleanName2+"last.html"
    URLS.append(Link)
for URL in URLS:
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(URL)
    except URLError, e:
        if e.code ==404:
            continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    statements = soup.findAll ('p',{ "class" : "Last Statement:" })
    print statements

csvfile.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The code is messy, I know. Once everything works I will clean it up. One problem though. I'm trying to get all the statements by using soup.findall, but I cannot seem to get the class right. The relevant part of the page source looks like this:

```
<p class="text_bold">Last Statement:</p>
<p>I don't have anything to say, you can proceed Warden Jones.</p>
```

However, the output of my program:

```
[]
[]
[]
```

...
What could be the problem exactly?

Comment: What is the problem, exactly?  Separating the "last statements" from other page content?

Comment: John Gordon: Well, the statements are not in a table. Check this link for example: http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/vargakevinlast.html  I don't understand how to grab the last statements of each of these pages.

Comment: You could look for `<p class="text_bold">Last Statement:   </p>` and then grab the following `<p>`...

Comment: Where is your code up to now?

Comment: I don't see any code at all related to scraping?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I know. I updated my post with new code. I have stumbled upon a problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not write code that solves the problem, but will give you a simple plan for how to do it yourself:

You know that each last statement is located at the URL:

```
http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_info/[lastname][firstname]last.html
```

You say you already have all the other information. This presumably includes the list of executed prisoners. So you should generate a list of names in your python code. This will allow you to generate the URL to get to each page you need to get to.

Then make a For loop that iterates over each URL using the format I posted above.

Within the body of this for loop, write code to read the page and get the last statement. The last statement on each page is in the same format on each page, so you can use parsing to capture the part that you want:

```
<p class="text_bold">Last Statement:</p>
<p>D.J., Laurie, Dr. Wheat, about all I can say is goodbye, and for all the rest of you, although you don&rsquo;t forgive me for my transgressions, I forgive yours against me. I am ready to begin my journey and that&rsquo;s all I have to say.</p>
```

Once you have your list of last statements, you can push them to SQL.

So your code will look like this:

```
import urllib2
# Make a list of names ('Last1First1','Last2First2','Last3First3',...)
names = #some_call_to_your_database
# Make a list of URLs to each inmate's last words page
# ('URL...Last1First1last.html',URL...Last2First2last.html,...)
URLS = () # made from the 'names' list above

# Create a dictionary to hold all the last words:
LastWords = {}

# Iterate over each individual page
for eachURL in URLS:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(eachURL)
    html = response.read()
    ## Some prisoners had no last words, so those URLs will 404.
    if ...: # Handle those 404s here

    ## Code to parse the response, hunting specifically
    ## for the code block I mentioned above. Once you have the
    ## last words as a string, save to dictionary:
    LastWords['LastFirst'] = "LastFirst's last words."



# Now LastWords is a dictionary with all the last words!
# Write some more code to push the content of LastWords
# to your SQL database.
```

Comment: This looks great! Will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck! Please upvote if you find it helpful! Post more specific questions with samples of your code as you get going :)

Comment: I did, but my reputation is too low for it to show on public :)